# Remote desktop to macOS from Windows using all local monitors

Tags: windows, catalina, remote-desktop

I have a Windows machine with multiple screens attached.
What I would like to do, is "remote desktop" into my MacBook Pro (Early 2015 model) and use all the screens I have locally (on the Windows machine), even though there are no external displays connected to the macOS machine.

I know Windows RDP has an option for this when connecting to Windows machines. Unfortunately I have not seen a similar option for macOS, as the remote desktop stuff mainly seems to revolve around VNC.
Is there any software available to still achieve the scenario mentioned above?